# I cannot "call decrypt_file()", how to do this properly?

Tags: python

I want to be able to select one of the options by typing the name out but this method does not work.

```
def sys():
    if input() == "en":
        encrypt_file()

    if input() == "de":
        decrypt_file()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I see at least three problems with this code: 1) `sys()` is never called. 2) `input()` is called more than once, but I assume it's not supposed to be. 3) `encrypt_file` and `decrypt_file` are not defined. So, for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code, input, expected output, and actual output (meaning the full error, if you're getting an error).

Comment: additionally, naming a function literally `sys` clobbers a builtin lib ([`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)) in that namespace which may give surprising results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` is called for each occurrence i.e. twice. I'm not sure if that's intended, but `decrypt_file()` will be called after the second input e.g.:

```
<run>
"en"
<enter>
<encrypt_file() is executed>
"de"
<enter>
<decrypt_file() is executed>
```

Better use single `input()` call and *then* do conditions e.g.:

```
value = input("Type here: ")
if value == "en":
    encrypt_file()
elif value == "de":
    decrypt_file()
```

Also you used `if` twice therefore the condition blocks are not connected, or in other words the check for `encrypt_file()` and for `decrypt_file()` are executed one after another, always. However, if you connect the condition blocks (with `elif` and `else`), it'll be checked for the first occurrence and then only the first matching block will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Just assign value of input to a variable. Then pass it as an argument in the function. Also `.lower()` will remove the case sensetivity.

```
def sys_check(inp):
    if inp.lower() == "en":
        encrypt_file()

    elif inp.lower() == "de":
        decrypt_file()
x=input("Enter 'en' for encrypting and 'de' for decrypting: ")
sys_check(x)
```

However, just to make the code simpler:

```
inp=input("Enter 'en' for encrypting and 'de' for decrypting: ")
if inp.lower() == "en":
    encrypt_file()

if inp.lower() == "de":
    decrypt_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `input()` just once and save it to a variable there. The way your code is organized, it takes the input and only if it's `'en'` will it encrypt. Whether it passed that part or not, it'd then go down to your next `if` statement and try to get input from the user again. If you entered `'de'` the first time around, you've lost the input from then.